# Change view controller on device rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on my first Xcode project and I am wondering if it is possible to have 2 view controllers, one which will have a portrait view and the second that will have horizontal. Is there any way I can link these 2 view controllers up so that when the device is rotated the view will change?

Comment: Are you looking to have a completely different view on rotation or do you just want the subviews to adjust their size? If the latter, you should use AutoLayout or Size Classes instead.

Comment: I want a completely different view when it is rotated

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad, add the rotated view to the superview and register an observer to UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification with an object:[UIDevice currentDevice]. 
On the selector set its frame. Then rotate the new rotated view, and set the old view's alpha to 0.0

```
- (void)deviceOrientationChangedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
     UIDevice *device = [notification object];
     UIDeviceOrientation orientation = device.orientation;

     if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
     {
        [rotatedView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];
        rotatedView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
        oldView.alpha = 0.0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Where do you "add the rotated view to the superview" in your example code?

Comment: I stand corrected, I add the view as subview in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend you to do that, because there are some intuitives UI controllers that apple has designed to manage the navigation of the app, you can't let the users to guess how to do some tasks in your app, you have to show them exactly how to do it. 
 So, rotate the device to go to another view controller, as you said :I want a completely different view when it is rotated... Is not a good idea.

Read the complete iOS Human Interface Guidelines to see what's recommended and what's not:

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html)

In particular, read: [Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH54-SW1):

> **Avoid gratuitous changes in layout.** A comparable experience in all environments lets people maintain their usage patterns when they rotate a device or run your app on a different device. For example, if you use a grid to display images in a horizontally regular environment, you don’t have to display the same information in a list in a horizontally compact environment, although you might adjust the dimensions of the grid.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on the reason you recommend against it? The HIG covers a lot of ground -- providing just that link doesn't really help explain your reasoning. (Also, it's never a good idea to make your answer rely entirely on a link -- links do break.)

Comment: It isn't a good Idea that to change to another viewController I have to rotate the divice, that is not an intuitive and correct way to manage the navigation of the app (that is whats he wants). Is obvious that he is a very amateur and hasn't read the guide of apple about the iOS inteface (what I recommended him with the link, and I wont explain all the guide to him by this way lol).

Comment: It's not uncommon for an app to present itself differently in different orientations -- try rotating Apple's "Stocks" app for example. Sometimes a single view controller can manage both orientations, but at the same time it may make sense to use separate controllers for each orientation. Note that the word *gratuitous* does not mean *all*. I'm not saying that you're wrong, just that it's impossible to understand your recommendation unless you explain it.

Comment: Yes I know. We can manage the appearance of the App in differents orientations. But perform a segue or present other view controller, for example, is not a practical way to manage the appearance or distribution of the App's UI elements. However, you're not wrong too, my answer could be better. Thank you!